# My wordpress site in a local (xampp) server now shows "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: database, wordpress

[image: Error Image]

The site was completely fine but once I uninstalled xampp and again installed it. The site folder is inside htdocs folder. Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling and re-installing XAMPP, your database related to the WordPress site might got deleted. Try re-creating a database with the same name or create a new database and edit your `wp-config.php` file's `DB_NAME` key with the new database value.

Comment: I created new database and addded it in wp-config.php but when i try locolhost/sitename it opens the installation page. Any suggestion?

Comment: It is because the current database is blank and you need to re-install WordPress in order to work with it

Comment: re-installing wordpress? I didn't get it. Would you mind ellaborating it?

Comment: Sure. Since your database got deleted, all the configurations and data related to your WordPress Website has been lost. That's why you're re-redirecting into the WordPress setup page. To work with the website again, you have to go through the setup process. That's what I mentioned as "re-installing WordPress"

Comment: I have done it but now i am getting complete new site after entering localhost/name

Comment: It is because your database has been deleted when you uninstall and re-install your XAMPP

Comment: So what is its solution?